# How to only select a displayed element using CSS

Tags: css, selenium, webdriver

In my program, I have a text element that displays in 2 different sections. It will display is section A, and again in section B (popup). I was hoping to create 1 object using CSS that could be used for both sections. That way I could call the same object to check this element regardless of where it is displayed. I can't seem to figure it out. Maybe its not possible, or maybe I need someone who has more experience with HTML and CSS to show me the light.

**Here is the HTML for this element in section A when it is displayed**

```
<td id="treeCol" valign="top" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;">
 <div id="orgTreeAndSearch">
  <div class="orgSelection">
   <span id="selection" class="" title="Select an org unit">Select an org unit</span>
```

**Here is the HTML for this element in section A when it is NOT displayed (hidden when section B is displayed)**

```
<td id="treeCol" valign="top" style="overflow: hidden; display: none;">
 <div id="orgTreeAndSearch">
  <div class="orgSelection">
   <span id="selection" class="" title="Select an org unit">Select an org unit</span>
```

**Here is the HTML for this element in section B when it is displayed**

```
<div class="blockUI blockMsg blockPage PopUp White" style="z-index: 1011; position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 1365px; top: 50px; left: 50px; text-align: left; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 0px none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
 <div class="White" style="margin: 0px 20px 20px; display: block;">
  <div class="PopUpClose" align="right">
   <div>
    <div align="center">
     <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="left" style="width: 410px;">
         <div class="orgSelection">
          <span id="dataAccessOrgSelection" class="">Select org unit(s)</span>
```

**Here is the HTML for this element in section B when it is NOT displayed (hidden when section A is displayed)**

```
<div class="White" style="margin: 0px 20px 20px; display: none;">
 <div class="PopUpClose" align="right">
  <div>
   <div align="center">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td valign="top" align="left" style="width: 410px;">
        <div class="orgSelection">
         <span id="dataAccessOrgSelection" class="">Select org unit(s)</span>
```

To select the element in section A, I could use the ID and it will work

```
css=#selection
```

To select the element in section B, I could also use it's id and it will work

```
css=#dataAccessOrgSelection
```

I wanted to have 1 selector for this element, so I tried this. However, it selects both the displayed and hidden elements. So if I'm on section A, it will select the element for both A and B, even though B is hidden (and vice-versa)

```
div.orgSelection span[id]
```

Is there a way to have 1 selector for this element, that will only select the visible element? I could check for "display:none" in the style attribute, but I'm not sure how to do this when it is located in td for section A, and div for section B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, if I understand your question right, you need CSS selector valid for both A and B in visible state.

```
td#treeCol[style*=block] span#selection, div.PopUp>div[style*=block] span#dataAccessOrgSelection
```

A tiny explanation. Comma - is for logical `OR` in CSS selectors. Visible `divs` of yours have a part of their `style` attribute - `block` (`[style*=block]`). So for both selectors we find `span` with needed `id` being contained inside a visible `div`. If the sectors are not right enough, play with attributes a little more.

To be completely sure that your approach works, you should call the element location with this selector every time before checking its visibility to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException`, because, clearly, those elements are not the same

But, if I was you, I would check a specific logic and not the 'what if' case. You should know exactly when and what element should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

As Alexander Petrovich mentioned, I would recommand to use to different element-selectors, because in my opinion, they are indeed different elements. In this case, you can find easy selectors with ids.

But if there's a valid reason for a one-selector-but-two-elements-constuct, you need to make clear, which parts of your dom may vary and which are stable. I'm not so firm with css, but I can give you some xpath expressions, if this helps:

- `//span[(@id='dataAccessOrgSelection') or (@id='selection')]`
- `//span[@class='']`
- `//span[contains(text(),'Select') and contains(text(),'org unit')]`
- `//div[@class='orgSelection']/span`

I guess you will be able to transform this xpath-selectors into css-selectors...maybe this pdf will help:
http://code.google.com/p/timger-book/source/browse/trunk/cheatsheet/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf

Comment: Guess, the main problem for both xpath and css is the way too complex selector. As I've already said I'd use two simple selectors and some logic (`if-else` ?)